# Adding Navigation Item SHRINKS everything in view

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, autolayout

I am new to swift/ xcode and am working out of a book which doesn't explain very well. I have a form layout inside a scroll view that works very well in the simulator no matter what orientation the emulator is in. (took me awhile to get that right). Now I have to add a navigation item to the scene, and it works well until I add a title into the navigation item. After the title is added, the safe view area shrinks in width. Weirdly enough though, when I run the emulator again, everything looks fine on the emulator. Surely I am doing something wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried using suggested constraints and it gives me a whole bunch of red lines on margins.

[image: Before Adding Title]

[image: After adding title]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste a copy of the original view controller next to itself, let's call it controllerCopy. Add your title to the original view controller, delete all its views when they mess up. Copy the views from controllerCopy and paste them into the original controller.